# how call orleans grain method without reference grain interface?

Tags: orleans

For example, java web front can call the Grain method without referencing the Grain Interface based on Grain's interface name and method and parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Orleans documentation

> In order to invoke a grain, a caller must know the grain interface
>   that the grain class implements that includes the method that the
>   caller wants to call and the unique identity (key) of the target
>   grain.

Therefore your grain needs to implement its interface so that it can be addressed through a GrainClient. That if I understand the vague question correctly.